# Dynamically detect object properties in a dll passed from different project

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, class-library

I am building a generic usercontrol. which will be a combination of one label and one textbox. This will be a class library project.

Text of the label and textBox will be bounded from outside projects. In the projects where I imported the dll.

I am trying to make the user control fully generic. For say, I will send any object, and a property name of the object to the dll. dll will read the object, get the object properties, get value for the sent parameter and act as another ready controls in win forms.

```
myControl1.DataBindings.Add("DataSource",object,"PropertyName1");
```

By just saying that, myController1 will get the value associated with `PropertyName1` of the `object` and bind values with the textbox and label.

Answer (score 0):

You wanna use reflection for this. 
This is how you do it using an extension method, but you can easily make it a regular function if that's what you need. I tried to explain what it does with comments.

```
    public static T GetProperty<T>(this object obj, string name)
    {
        Type type = obj.GetType(); // Get the object's type
        PropertyInfo pinfo = type.GetProperty(name); // Get the property information for the specified property name
        object ret = pinfo?.GetValue(obj); // If pinfo != null, get the value of the property on obj

        return ret == null ? default(T) : (T)ret; // If ret is null, return the default value for T (for example, "" if T is string). If it isn't, return ret casted to T
    }
```

Usage example:

```
Form1.Text == Form1.GetProperty<string>("Text"); // true
```